# check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' '', , '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NOW())' at line 2

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting this error, i am new to programming, kindly please correct if i am wrong. Thank you

```
<?

$customername = $_REQUEST["customername"];
//$customername = strtoupper($customername);
//$customername = trim($customername);
$address1=$_REQUEST["address1"];
$address2=$_REQUEST["address2"];
$city  = $_REQUEST["city"];
$state  = $_REQUEST["state"];
$pincode = $_REQUEST["pincode"];
$phonenumber1 = $_REQUEST["phonenumber1"];
$phonenumber2 = $_REQUEST["phonenumber2"];
$emailid1  = $_REQUEST["emailid1"];
$mobilenumber  = $_REQUEST["mobilenumber"];


$sql = "insert into master_customer (id,customername,address1,address2,city,state,pincode,phonenumber1,phonenumber2,emailid1,mobilenumber)
                         values ('','$customername','$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$pincode','$phonenumber1','$phonenumber2','$emailid1','$mobilenumber')";
$exec = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in Query".mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: looks like you have two commas next to one another without an empty string in there.. make sure you're stripping out quotes etc if you're going to place your request values direct into an SQL query.. (imo this is a massive security risk currently)

Comment: I think the error message can not come from this statement. Is it possible that there is a trigger on this table?

Comment: In the error is specified the part NOW() this is on a date insertion query. You have provided irrelevant code. Try to find in your script the query that has to do with date.

Comment: this is not the query that generating the error, show us the actual query.

Comment: i cannot find anything else regarding to that error, db table giving an error? i doubt but. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this single line in place of all your code this will solve your problem.

```
$sql = mysql_query("insert into master_customer (id,customername,address1,address2,city,state,pincode,phonenumber1,phonenumber2,emailid1,mobilenumber) VALUES('','".$_REQUEST["customername"]."','".$_REQUEST["address1"]."','".$_REQUEST["address2"]."','".$_REQUEST["city"]."','".$_REQUEST["state"]."','".$_REQUEST["pincode"]."','".$_REQUEST["phonenumber1"]."','".$_REQUEST["phonenumber2"]."','".$_REQUEST["emailid1"]."','".$_REQUEST["mobilenumber"]."')");
```

There is no need of such a lengthy code.